# WordPress custom order field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, invoice

I have a requirement where, I have a list of pin codes which are serviceable by different courier partners. What I want is, Once someone books a order, I want to first check the pin code and accordingly add the respective Courier partner name in the order meta field. For that I have created a custom checkout field. And once someone submits the address I can check through the pincodes and add respective courier.

But now after this, I also have a list of awb numbers given by respective courier partners. And I would also like to add respective courier awb number to the order and also send the same in the order recived email to the customer.

I am looking out, is there any action hook from Woocommerce which allows me to check the pincode and accordingly add the AWB number and send the same to customer/admin invoice. The only twist is, I want to add a function of assigning awb number after the order is marked as processing and before email-invoice is sent to the customer.

Is there any action hook which allows me to get order detail and add awb number after order is set as processing and before email-invoice is sent to the customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try `woocommerce_order_status_processing` with a high priority.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'your_fn', 0);
function your_fn( $order_id ) 
{
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I did solved this with another method. But can someone tell me how do i send custom email to customer when the order is marked on hold. ?